# SocketAppender in OSGi / Fuse 7

Tags: log4j, osgi, log4j2, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

Using Fuse 7 (Karaf version 4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1)

Trying to get SocketAppender working.
Best guess was the following, added to `org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg`

```
# ELK appender
log4j2.appender.elk.type = SocketAppender
log4j2.appender.elk.name = ELK
log4j2.appender.elk.remoteHost=10.0.0.2
log4j2.appender.elk.port=12202
log4j2.appender.elk.application=QA
log4j2.appender.elk.reconnectionDelay=0
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.ELK.ref = ELK
```

But that just stops all logs, even the console.

I'm actually trying to get the [logstash-gelf appender](https://logging.paluch.biz/examples/log4j-2.x.html) working, but using a custom appender in Fuse 7 / Karaf looks like a total mess.  (See [link](https://medium.com/@azinneera/configuring-log4j-2-in-osgi-environment-70be42e95ef8)).  I doubt it would ever work.

SocketAppender was working fine with log4j in Fuse 6.
Main difference in the setup was this line, which isn't applicable to log4j2 now:

```
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer
```

------------- EDIT:

```
    # ELK appender
log4j2.appender.elk.type = Socket
log4j2.appender.elk.name = ELK
log4j2.appender.elk.layout.type = GelfLayout
log4j2.appender.elk.remoteHost=10.0.0.2
log4j2.appender.elk.port=12202
log4j2.appender.elk.application=QA
log4j2.appender.elk.reconnectionDelay=0
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.ELK.ref = ELK
```

This isn't killing the logs at least.  Also found GelfLayout, which might be able to replace the logstash-gelf appender, if it was working.

------------- EDIT 2 ---- Reply to Grzegorz:

Thanks for the reply... unfortunately not working still...
I've changed the lines to the following, as described:

```
# ELK appender
log4j2.appender.socket.type = Socket
log4j2.appender.socket.name = Socket
log4j2.appender.socket.host=localhost
log4j2.appender.socket.port=12202
log4j2.appender.socket.protocol=TCP
log4j2.appender.socket.layout.type = JsonLayout

log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.Socket.ref = Socket
```

And start running netcat

```
[root@ldkr03 etc]# nc -lk 12202
(not showing anything...)
```

The `log:log test` shows  `16:10:34.747 INFO [pipe-log:log test] test` but doesn't show anything in the `nc -lk 12202` window.

Also, maybe relevant, though it writes to the Console just fine:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

------------- EDIT 3 ----

Switched to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But still no.

Comment: Ok, well "log4j2.appender.elk.type = Socket" stopped it from crashing the whole logging system, at least... but the SocketAppender still isn't working.

Comment: Ok it's working now.  Derp.  Not sure what I did, but something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this configuration for appender:

```
log4j2.appender.socket.type = Socket
log4j2.appender.socket.name = Socket
log4j2.appender.socket.host = localhost
log4j2.appender.socket.port = 5666
log4j2.appender.socket.protocol = TCP
log4j2.appender.socket.layout.type = JsonLayout
```

and this to attach this appender to root logger:

```
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.Socket.ref = Socket
```

I started `nc` using `nc -lk 5666` and produced log entries using `log:log asd` from Karaf shell console. Netcat was printing something like this:

```
{
  "timeMillis" : 1549546648409,
  "thread" : "pipe-log:log asd",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "org.apache.karaf.log.core",
  "message" : "asd",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggingServiceImpl",
  "threadId" : 172,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
```

If you check https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender there's no `remoteHost` property, but `host`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not working yet... please see reply in main post

Comment: Working now.  I think my issue was sending it to localhost inside docker, but running nc on the host. It worked when I ran nc on another machine. If you have a moment, do please take a look at my next issue. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691259/log4j2-socketappender-gelflayout